# Thinking Texture Coordinate

Tags: node-editor, texture-coordinates

I made double circle at center of red square like a picture below and added Noise Texture Node with Scale Node.
After this,Double circle with noise came (-0.5,-0.5).
I would understand if it came positive coordinate but it came negative.
Why it did not came positive but negative?

[image]

Comment: You are using object coordinates.  They range from 0 to 1  in each dimension, so the center of a square would be at (.5, .5).  The equation of a circle is set to use the origin as its center, so you have to offset it by (.5, .5) to center it at the center of the square.

Comment: So the center of a square moved (0,0) to (0.5,0.5) after adding noise tex and it just looked like double circle came to (-0.5,-0.5) due to this?

Comment: The noise texture is perturbing the circle by adding random values in the range of 0 to 1, with an average of .5, yes.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for answering and taking your time.